# Upload gif images in Laravel 5.7

Tags: intervention

I am trying to upload an gif image.It displays the image with first frame and animation get disappears. Here is my code to upload an image . it is because of Image intervention does not support gif. Is there an alternative method to upload an image

```
        if($request->image ){
        $name = time().'.' . explode('/', explode(':', substr($request->image, 0, strpos($request->image, ';')))[1])[1];


        \Image::make($request->image)->save(public_path('img/').$name);
        $request->merge(['image' => $name]);


    }
```

Comment: _It is because of Image intervention does not support gif._ Well there’s not really much you can do if the issue is with Intervention. You’ll need to use an image processing library that _does_ support animated GIFs.

Comment: What other library to use . Can you help with sample of code

Comment: @Martin Bean Is there an alternative  library

Comment: “Questions asking [Stack Overflow] to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.” https://stackoverflow.com/tour